# Git Project won't run locally on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

So I'm having trouble running my git repo locally. I had been running it fine in the past but after some errors I needed to re-clone the repo.  Since then I have not been able to run my program.  I can still edit and push/commit but just can't run it locally.I believe it might have to do that Eclipse is not recognizing it as a Java Project.  If I try to right click the project and configure, the only available options are: "configure and detect nested projects" or "convert to Maven Project

[Package Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sde5A.png)

If I try to run it is just not recognizing the project at all.  If I go into run Configurations and select Java Application, the project is able to be found.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the project file anymore. Try creating a new project from the repo.

Comment: The `.project` file won't be version controlled. So eclipse won't recognize the project. You can create a new project and copy the contents over.